# derivation for entropy regularised RL

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

The objective for entropy-regularised RL is to find the policy that maximises the objective below.

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\pi\left(a_{t} | s_{t}\right)} Q\left(s_{t}, a_{t}\right)-\mathrm{KL}\left(\pi\left(\cdot | s_{t}\right) \| \pi_{0}\left(\cdot | s_{t}\right)\right)
$$

I am trying to derive the policy, however I am getting a slightly different answer to the correct answer.

My derivation is as follows (I ignore writing the $s$ and $a$ in $Q(s|a)$ below for brevity):

First I rewrite the objective as an integral

$$
\int Q \cdot \pi-\pi \ln \left(\frac{\pi}{\pi_{0}}\right) d a d s
$$

$$
\int \pi\left(Q-\ln \left(\frac{\pi}{\pi_{0}}\right)\right) d a d s
$$

In order to find the policy $\pi$ that maximises the objective, I differentiate it with respect to $\pi$ *using product rule* and set it equal to zero.

$$
Q-\ln \left(\frac{\pi}{\pi_{0}}\right)+\pi\left(\frac{d Q}{d \pi}+\frac{1}{\pi} \ln \pi_{0}\right)=0
$$

$$
Q-\ln \pi+\pi \frac{d Q}{d \pi}=0
$$

Which has the trivial solution:

$$
\pi=e^{Q}
$$

However the actual answer is:

$$
\pi = \pi_{0}\left(a_{t} | s_{t}\right) e^ {Q\left(s_{t}, a_{t}\right)-V_{Q}\left(s_{t}\right)}
$$

where

$$
V_{Q}\left(s_{t}\right)=\log \mathbb{E}_{a \sim p_{0}} \exp \left\{Q\left(s_{t}, a_{t}\right)\right\}
$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: do you have a source for this? Q(s,a) - V(s) looks like an advantage function to me. Could just be that they slipped this in without mention? Also, are you sure differentiating with respect to the policy 'removes' the integral over states?

Comment: If you are taking integral over $a$ and $s$ then you should have double integral not a single one, but I think integration over states is not necessary since you are taking expectation over policy so you should integrate over actions only and state is given ? (not sure on this). With that being said $V(s_t)$ is usually used as a baseline for variance reduction because it doesn't depend on action (but it does on state, which makes me think integral is only over actions), you can use it to reduce variance without changing the result, so I guess that's what they did here.